# need instructions with WCF and MVC 4 desgin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

i have a design question.
i'm building a portal that consume third party services.

I have put this service into a DLL and when initialize one DLL class i pass the service address for one service (and so on to the rest of the services - some of them with different address)

```
 public LogonService (string address)
        {
            EndpointAddress epA = new EndpointAddress ( address );
            proxyClient = new LogonServicePortTypeClient ( "LogonServicePort" , epA);
            //added this InspectorBehavior for logging and errrors
            proxyClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add ( new InspectorBehavior () );

        }
```

this is my constructor.
then in instance i have all the LogonService capabilities exposed (login , logout,refresh etc - again , this is one example of one service. there are few of them).

this DLL is used by an MVC 4 internet application.
i thought to **add a BusinessLogic folder to hold a class per DLL class, that will initiate the service as shown  and  communicate the result to the Controllers** in a manner that a controller can understand.
( this is my idea of design)

if ( again IF) this design in agreeable i would like to know what where and how will the best practice of initializing these DLL classes , storing them for reuse ,etc.

to summarize my long question :
1. Is this a valid design?
2. Where in the application life should i initialize these Dll classes ?
3. How would i store these service instances (performance respect) ?
4. last ,if this design is not logical what then will a recommended design ?

Thanks 
Gilad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is to go for a DI framework like Castle or Unity. That'll take away a lot of headache for class initialization, and will make your classes more testable.

Also, externalize your end-point configuration to an xml (under the system.serviceModel section). I feel that a fluent end-point configuration is quite distracting.

Comment: thanks.i will check the Unity framework now. i can't put the address in a config file because it might changed as the 3rd party service is also a "Product" that can be sell to many different customers which will implement it (thus giving it a different address each time)

Comment: though it is not a complete answer , after several days , i found that Unity is a great way to "sort" thing up, or out ....Thanks for pointing Unity to me

Answer (score 0):

I walked into this exact same question a few month ago, sadly I didn't had the privilege to spend time addressing it. As far as I can tell your design is good, it's also the one I have adopted.

I'm more concerning about your 3) question. I ended up by creating a service instance for each WS calls (Since only a few users were using the web app and really not often, I didn't cared to much about performances). However I would be very interested in someone opinion on that point.

I also agree with the comment from aquaraga. You should use as much as you can the configuration file. I went into to many troubles when developers hardcoded part of the configuration into their application.

Comment: thanks for the response. the reason i'm not using config file is to give a user the opportunity to choose his provider.by giving the option to enter provider details in login page.this makes the site more generic and testable from many environments - not only the one hard coded in the configuration file.